# Topic Modelling in an existing dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, topic-model, lda

I am trying to perform topic extraction in a panda dataframe.  I am using LDA topic modeling in order to extract the topics in my dataframe.  No problem.

But, I would like to apply LDA topic modeling to each row in my dataframe.

**Current datafame:**

| date | cust_id | words |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3/14/2019 | 100001 | samantha slip skirt pi ski |
| 1/21/2020 | 10002 | steel skirt solid greenish |
| 5/19/2020 | 10003 | arizona denim blouse d |

**The dataframe I am looking for:**

| date | cust_id | words | topic 0 words | topic 0 weights |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/14/2019 | 100001 | samantha slip skirt pi ski | skirt | 0.5 |
| 1/21/2020 | 10002 | skirt solid greenish | greenish | 0.2 |
| 5/19/2020 | 10003 | arizona denim blouse | denim | 01 |

---

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.9, min_df=20, token_pattern='\w+|\$[\d.]+|\S+')

tf = vectorizer.fit_transform(features['words']).toarray()

tf_feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

number_of_topics = 6
model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=number_of_topics, random_state=1111)

model.fit(tf)

---

I tried to merge two dataframe together, it does not work.
How will I be able to add each topic in each column and add each topic weights to add to all my rows?

I posted the question in stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71476309/topic-modelling-in-an-existing-dataframe-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=lda_model, corpus=corpus, texts=data):
   
    sent_topics_df = pd.DataFrame()

   
    for i, row in enumerate(ldamodel[corpus]):
        row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
        # Get the Dominant topic, Perc Contribution and Keywords for each document
        for j, (topic_num, prop_topic) in enumerate(row):
            if j == 0:  # -- dominant topic
                wp = ldamodel.show_topic(topic_num)
                topic_keywords = ", ".join([word for word, prop in wp])
                sent_topics_df = sent_topics_df.append(pd.Series([int(topic_num), round(prop_topic,4), topic_keywords]), ignore_index=True)
            else:
                break
    sent_topics_df.columns = ['Dominant_Topic', 'Perc_Contribution', 'Topic_Keywords']

    # Add original text to the end of the output
    
    contents = pd.Series(texts)
    sent_topics_df = pd.concat([sent_topics_df, contents], axis=1)
    return(sent_topics_df)
    

df_topic_sents_keywords = format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=optimal_model, corpus=corpus, texts=df)


df_dominant_topic = df_topic_sents_keywords.reset_index()
df_dominant_topic.columns = ['Document_No', 'Dominant_Topic', 'Topic_Perc_Contrib', 'Keywords', 'Text']


df_dominant_topic.head(5)
```

You can find the detailed implementation in this **[Kaggle Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/akashram/topic-modeling-intro-implementation/notebook)**

Comment: I did go another way, but this is awesome.  I'm sure, I will use it for fun.  THANK YOU LOVE!!!!!!  I did share the answer on Twitter.